# Triggering DAG in a loop

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am trying to trigger DAG task for 3 times , how can this be done using python script.

Currently my flow job is

> dag = DAG('dag1', default_args=default_args,    concurrency=1,
> max_active_runs=1,
> schedule_interval=None, catchup=False)
>
> task = BashOperator(
> task_id='task1',
> bash_command='ssh  "runJob.sh"',
> dag=dag)

Is there any better way to trigger job for a given specified number of times ?

Answer (score 1):

In airflow Airflow 2.0 you can use the `TriggerDagRunOperator`. 
You should be able to use that in a loop.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html

```
 trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id="some-id",
        trigger_dag_id="dag1",
        conf={"some_param": 'some_value'},    
        reset_dag_run = True
    )
```

Alternatively you can also put in the a task and call the execute method,
like `TriggerDagRunOperator(...).execute()` and pass in the current context to the execute method 
which you can find using the `get_current_context` function from `airflow.operators.python`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use Airflow 2, you can use the following command to trigger a DAG run.

```
airflow dags trigger [-h] [-c CONF] [-e EXEC_DATE] [-r RUN_ID] [-S SUBDIR] dag_id
```

You can read more on [this command here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#trigger).

Based on that command, we can use use `subprocess` to run it.

```
import subprocess
command = [
    "airflow",
    "dags",
    "trigger",
    "-e",
    "2021-02-05 00:00:00",
    "-r",
    "manual__2021-02-05T00:00:00+00:00",
    "my_dag",
]

for i in range(3):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
```

Comment: thank you , one doubt  "command.split()" what is being split here ??

Comment: "my_dag" is dag name right , how are you refering it in for loop ?

Comment: I tried to generate command args by splitting a string command but didn't work and forgot to take out the split.

Comment: Sorry for down voting - A better solution would be if it is found inside airflow ecosystem. Like Sub-Dags or Dynamic Tasks.